# How to show Random products in category view page Magento2?

Tags: magento2, magento2.3, magento2.2

Here is my code -

Code of **`di.xml`** file -

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<config xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:noNamespaceSchemaLocation="urn:magento:framework:ObjectManager/etc/config.xsd">
    <type name="Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer">
        <plugin name="LayerPlugin" type="Vishal\ConfigPrice\Plugin\Model\Layer" sortOrder="1"/>
    </type>
</config>
```

Code of Model Plugin -

```
<?php

namespace Vishal\ConfigPrice\Plugin\Model;

use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;

class Layer
{
    /**
     * Product collections array
     *
     * @var array
     */
    protected $_productCollections = [];

    /**
     * Key which can be used for load/save aggregation data
     *
     * @var string
     */
    protected $_stateKey = null;

    /**
     * Core registry
     *
     * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
     */
    protected $registry = null;

    /**
     * Store manager
     *
     * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
     */
    protected $_storeManager;

    /**
     * Catalog product
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
     */
    protected $_catalogProduct;

    /**
     * Attribute collection factory
     *
     * @var AttributeCollectionFactory
     */
    protected $_attributeCollectionFactory;

    /**
     * Layer state factory
     *
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory
     */
    protected $_layerStateFactory;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ItemCollectionProviderInterface
     */
    protected $collectionProvider;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey
     */
    protected $stateKeyGenerator;

    /**
     * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter
     */
    protected $collectionFilter;

    /**
     * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
     */
    protected $categoryRepository;

    /**
     * @param Layer\ContextInterface $context
     * @param Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory
     * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
     * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct
     * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
     * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
     * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
     * @param array $data
     */
    public function __construct(
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
        AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
        \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
        \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
        \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
        CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
        array $data = []
    ) {
        $this->_layerStateFactory = $layerStateFactory;
        $this->_attributeCollectionFactory = $attributeCollectionFactory;
        $this->_catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
        $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
        $this->registry = $registry;
        $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository; 

    }

    public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, $result)
    {
        $result->setOrder('rand()');
        // echo "==-->>>==<pre>"; print_r($result->getData()); die;
        return $result;
    }
}
```

**But no luck !!! Please help me....**

Answer (score 0):

Replace the below code with your **model plugin** ,

```
<?php
    
    namespace Vishal\ConfigPrice\Plugin\Model;
    
    use Magento\Catalog\Api\CategoryRepositoryInterface;
    use Magento\Framework\Exception\NoSuchEntityException;
    use Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product\Attribute\CollectionFactory as AttributeCollectionFactory;
    
    class Layer
    {
        /**
         * Product collections array
         *
         * @var array
         */
        protected $_productCollections = [];
    
        /**
         * Key which can be used for load/save aggregation data
         *
         * @var string
         */
        protected $_stateKey = null;
    
        /**
         * Core registry
         *
         * @var \Magento\Framework\Registry
         */
        protected $registry = null;
    
        /**
         * Store manager
         *
         * @var \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface
         */
        protected $_storeManager;
    
        /**
         * Catalog product
         *
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product
         */
        protected $_catalogProduct;
    
        /**
         * Attribute collection factory
         *
         * @var AttributeCollectionFactory
         */
        protected $_attributeCollectionFactory;
    
        /**
         * Layer state factory
         *
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory
         */
        protected $_layerStateFactory;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\ItemCollectionProviderInterface
         */
        protected $collectionProvider;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\StateKey
         */
        protected $stateKeyGenerator;
    
        /**
         * @var \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\Category\CollectionFilter
         */
        protected $collectionFilter;
    
        /**
         * @var CategoryRepositoryInterface
         */
        protected $categoryRepository;
    
        /**
         * @param Layer\ContextInterface $context
         * @param Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory
         * @param AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory
         * @param \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct
         * @param \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager
         * @param \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry
         * @param CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository
         * @param array $data
         */
        public function __construct(
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer\StateFactory $layerStateFactory,
            AttributeCollectionFactory $attributeCollectionFactory,
            \Magento\Catalog\Model\ResourceModel\Product $catalogProduct,
            \Magento\Store\Model\StoreManagerInterface $storeManager,
            \Magento\Framework\Registry $registry,
            CategoryRepositoryInterface $categoryRepository,
            array $data = []
        ) {
            $this->_layerStateFactory = $layerStateFactory;
            $this->_attributeCollectionFactory = $attributeCollectionFactory;
            $this->_catalogProduct = $catalogProduct;
            $this->_storeManager = $storeManager;
            $this->registry = $registry;
            $this->categoryRepository = $categoryRepository; 
    
        }
    
        public function afterGetProductCollection(\Magento\Catalog\Model\Layer $subject, $result)
        {
            $result->getSelect()->orderRand();
            return $result;
        }
    }
```